# Error : No ESLint configuration found

Tags: javascript, json, gulp, eslint, grunt-eslint

Can't get ESLint recognize and running using Gulp. Code for gulpfile.js is:

```js
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect'); //Runs a local dev server
var open = require('gulp-open'); //Open a URL in a web browser
var browserify = require('browserify'); // Bundles JS
var reactify = require('reactify');  // Transforms React JSX to JS
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); // Use conventional text streams with Gulp
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); //Concatenates files
var lint = require('gulp-eslint'); //Lint JS files, including JSX

var config = {
 port: 9005,
 devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
 paths: {
  html: './src/*.html',
  js: './src/**/*.js',
  css: [
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
     ],
  dist: './dist',
  mainJs: './src/main.js'
 }
}

//Start a local development server
gulp.task('connect', function() {
 connect.server({
  root: ['dist'],
  port: config.port,
  base: config.devBaseUrl,
  livereload: true
 });
});

gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function() {
 gulp.src('dist/index.html')
  .pipe(open({ url: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}));
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
 gulp.src(config.paths.html)
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
 browserify(config.paths.mainJs)
  .transform(reactify)
  .bundle()
  .on('error', console.error.bind(console))
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/scripts'))
  .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
 gulp.src(config.paths.css)
  .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/css'));
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
 return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
  .pipe(lint({config: 'eslint.config.json'}))
  .pipe(lint.format());
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
 gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js', 'lint']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'js', 'css', 'lint', 'open', 'watch']);
```

and eslint.config.json is :

```js
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": 0,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-lone-blocks": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    jQuery: true,
    $: true
  }
}
```

and finally package.json dependencies are:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "browserify": "^14.1.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-open": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
```

What can I edit to get one or more of the three files to work?

Comment: Have you tried setting the root path like `.pipe(lint({config: './eslint.config.json'}))` because I assume both files are in the same directory right?

Answer (score 5):

As you can read at https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint#optionsconfigfile

Key name has changed to `configFile`

Comment: I was also following the Pluralsight React course, but with the latest node packages as of this date, and this fixed it for me

Answer (score 5):

Please rename ***eslint.config.json*** filename to ***.eslintrc*** .
Then change the ***lint*** gulp task as following.

```
    gulp.task('lint', function() {
        return gulp.src(config.paths.js)
            .pipe(lint.format());
    });
```

Comment: Totally just worked for me. I believe the person asking this question is following along with a Pluralsight training video, same as me, as their file looks like what I have at the moment. Regardless, this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
.pipe(lint({config: '.eslint.config.json'}))
```

or anything directly address the eslint config in your gulp config file